# Unexpected output from metropolis function in C

Tags: c

I'm currently writing some code for simulated annealing in C.  I'm having a trouble with this function:

```
int metrop (E, E1, T)
{
   int j;
   if (exp((-E-E1)/T) > ran())
    j = 2;
    printf("Random# %lf\n",ran());
   if (E-E1<0)
    j = 2;

   else
   j = 0;

   if (j=1)
    printf("Accepted %d",j);
   if (j=0)
    printf("Rejected");
   return(j);
}
```

Regardless of the input for E,E1,and T, "if (j=1) printf("Accepted %lf",j);" seems to be executed;giving an output of "Accepted 1". Even though in this code it isn't possible for j to be equal to 1.  I suspect I may be referencing the wrong data types or something like that.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `if (j==1)`, not `if (j=1)`...

Comment: you have close to 0 experience with programming, right? Don't indent by 1, don't assume that indentation defines a block, don't assume that ran() returns the same number twice...

Comment: trying if(1==j) makes remembering easier and avoids these kind of obfuscations.

Comment: Ah hah! Yeah I have very little experience with C.  Thank you.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, I don't agree, you can read [my opinion on Yoda conditions here](http://compgroups.net/comp.programming/position-of-test-values-in-conditional-expre/547338) (just look for my name)

Comment: @Walter Tross you may be right to insist on conventional if() but this is just if you are %100 sure about what you are doing and you are not begineer. For example I am not %100 sure always so I do similar things  (null==whatever) to be %100 sure.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I'm 100% sure that your code is harder to read, debug and maintain because of this. I'll quote myself from the link above: "As others have already explained, it helps in avoiding the error of
writing an assignment where an equality comparison was intended.
I personally dislike this trick, because it only helps in **initially** avoiding a mistake, while the more difficult to read code **remains**.
If you rely on this kind of trick to write correct code, it means that you are not doing any testing, which is the worst mistake you can make."

Comment: @Walter Tross What if I dont want to test a file accessing function before it is mostly complete so I dont damage any data in it?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik if I continued this discussion I would risk to offend you, which is bad on SO

Comment: @Walter Tross Then I apology first to share my opinion.

Comment: another question if you guys don't mind.  After fixing the If statement, this piece of code: if (exp(-120/T) > ran())
   j = 1;  

Where T=1 returns a value of 1 for j.  If i remove T, it returns a value of zero. Do you know what is going on here?

Clearly exp(-120) is less than the random number being generated ( i think it was around 0.6.)

Comment: apart from the fact that I don't know how you can say what the random number *was* - do you have `#include <math.h>` in your code? Because if you haven't that 120 stays an integer while it should be converted to a double, and `exp()` will interpret it badly. And BTW, your function parameters have no type, meaning they are integers! You got to study a lot...

Comment: just enable compiler warnings. gcc can catch typos for == most of the time.

Comment: @Walter Tross the "random" numbers being generated are the same sequence of numbers each time i run the program. Thats how i knew what the number was.  I obviously need to fix this but that's another issue haha.  Thanks for the other tips though I think that was it.  And yes I do need to study if you know of any good resources I'd be grateful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
if (j == 1)  // j == 1 evaluates to true if j is 1, evaluates to false otherwise
```

Using:

```
if (j = 1)
```

Sets j equal to one and is essentially

```
if (1)  // always true
```